# greek letters in sqllite to process Greek Characters correctly

Tags: sqlite, unicode

I want to use SQLite for an lite application. How can I instruct SQLite to process Greek Characters correctly.
 I can see only ???? as Greek letters in result.

Comment: Why the T-SQL tag? Anyway, show the code that inserts the Greek text.

Comment: How does the text go into the database?

Comment: by TSQL insert statment

Comment: T-SQL is not SQLite. And how are you executing that statement?

Comment: i'm try insert into sqlite database by t_SQL all thing is ok ، Except Greek letters

Comment: What is that "t_SQL" that you are mentioning? (Do you think it is Microsoft SQL Server's dialect?) Do other non-ASCII characters work?